# WP_Query with tax_query, order by most 'matches'

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, order, tax-query

**TL;DR:** 
How can I sort a `WP_Query` based on how many 'matches' there are on the `tax_query` set. Furthermore, how can I then add more posts if the `posts_per_page` is not met due to the `tax_query` added?

**Full story:** 
Hi all,

I'm fairly new to `WP_Query` editing, therefore this question. I've checked out multiple posts already but can't seem to find the fitting answer.

I'm in the situation where I extend my `WP_Query` in the `pre_get_posts` hook. Here, I'm adding a `tax_query` to first receive posts that are in certain categories OR contain certain tags. This is (the interesting part of) the code I use in `pre_get_posts`:

```
$extend = [
    [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => [1, 2, 3],
            'include_children' => false
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => [6, 7, 8],
        ]
    ]
];
$query->set('tax_query', $extend);
```

Which actually gives me the results I want. Based on the original query, which has `cat => 4`, I only receive posts that have: 
- Category 4, AND;
- Either category 1/2/3 OR tag 6/7/8

Which is the desired effect. However, the problem comes when the query doesn't return enough results.

For example: The `posts_per_page` is set to 5 for example, and after the `pre_get_posts` hook the query only returns 3 posts. If this happens, I'd like to add another 2 posts to fill up to 5. These posts do not have to meet the `pre_get_posts` tax_query, but just the original query_vars. I've managed to get this working with another `found_posts` hook, on which I check how many posts I already have and if that's enough to meet the `posts_per_page` var. If it does not, it'll search for more posts and add those.

I'm not sure if implementing the `found_posts` hook is the way to go here, as I'd like to sort the posts based on how many 'matches' they have in the `tax_query` first, and then add the other posts (that do not match) to the end, so that the posts with category or tag in the tax_query get displayed first.

Has anyone else encountered this before?

Looking forward to any help, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Did you find a solution to order by most matched?

Comment: Did you find a solution or back up plan?